# Is there a conventional/standard way to create an MFC error dialog?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2008

I'd like to create a dialog for my application that shows a message and displays the standard red circle with the white "x" in the middle; seems to me this is a pretty standard windows dialog. I'm somewhat new to MFC, so I don't know if there's a short-cut to do this other than creating a dialog resource, copying the image of the red x from [microsoft's best practices page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx), including that as a dialog item and then coding up my own. Surely there is a more standard way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
AfxMessageBox(_T("Something bad happened!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
```

See also [AfxMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: you answered the first part, thanks. Do you know an answer to the second part?

Comment: I edited the question, the second part is it's own question now.

Comment: Hi @Mike, did you post the second part as a new question? I do not see it.

Comment: are the MB_ICON* styles only supported if you're using AfxMessageBox? Are they supported in a normal CDialog instance?

Comment: @Mike, the MB_ICON* styles are only for AfxMessageBox. If you want to use the standard icons in a regular CDialog you can load them using [CWinApp::LoadStandardIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44s6bcez.aspx) or Win32 [LoadIcon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072.aspx) giving the standard resource ID from the table [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072.aspx). The one you want is [IDI_ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

If the user can take corrective action about the error and you are targeting Windows Vista or higher, you can use `CTaskDialog`. This lets you present the new "Task Dialog" with large action buttons. Here's a [tutorial](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/03/10/task-dialog-in-mfc/), and the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293651.aspx).

[image]

Comment: +1, it's been several years since I've done MFC. That looks like a powerful addition!